# Building fortran with llvm

Tags: fortran, clang, llvm

I've seen, that there is an considerable performance increase using llvm. Is there a way to compile a fortran code using llvm (or clang)?

Comment: What did your own research into this question reveal ?

Comment: Since clang is specifically a C compiler, that's a dead end. There is a project called [dragonegg](http://dragonegg.llvm.org/) which uses llvm as a backend and supports Fortrans.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark That was the confusing part because I found some performance tests where the compared gcc, intel and clang but I also thought it is not possible ....

Comment: @chthonicdaemon thx!!!

Comment: There was also some flang projects, but it appears to be currently inactive.